# ATmega8 LED blinking project not working properly

Tags: led, avr, atmega, c

I am making a simple project using ATmega8 microchip. I uploaded this code to the AVR:

```
#include avr/io.h
#include util/delay.h

int main(void) {
    DDRD = 0b10000000;
    DDRD = 0b01000000;

    while(1) {
        PORTD = 0b10000000;
        _delay_ms(100);
        PORTD = 0b00000000;
        PORTD = 0b01000000;
        _delay_ms(100);
        PORTD = 0b00000000;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It basically turns on and off two different LED's which are connected to pin `(AIN0) PD6` and `(AIN1) PD7`.

[image: ATmega8 datasheet]

When the system is working, the AVR can deliver power to just one of the LED's properly. Other LED has a significantly low brightness. When I measure the voltage delivered to the bright LED which is connected to `PD6`, it takes approximately 2.3 volts, and the dimmer one which is connected to `PD7` takes approximately 1.2 volts.

Why I am having this issue? Is it about the code that I wrote or is it about the chip itself? On the other hand when I light just one of the LED's on either `PD6` or `PD7` with a simple code it works just fine. So there is no problem with pins, connections or LED's I use. (I also could not copy and paste the package names here correctly! So it is correct too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your initialisation. First you set D7 as an output and all other pins on port D as a input. In your next statement you set D6 as an output and all other pins including D7 as an input.

To fix this use this instead of both initialisations:

DDRD = 0b11000000;

you can also use this:

DDRD = 0b10000000; 
DDRD |= 0b01000000;

if you want to setup more outputs use |= instead of =.

Comment: The reason is obvious, one LED at PD7 is powered via AVR internal pull-up.

To avoid copy&pasting you can use PIND write to invert particular PORTD bit.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. I am sure that will solve the problem.